# How to join, merge multiple files with duplicate key and fill void columns by using AWK

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, left-join

Join and merge multiple files with duplicate key and fill void columns

I have many files that I want to merge:

file1.csv:

```
1|abc
1|def
2|ghi
2|jkl
3|mno
3|pqr
```

file2.csv:

```
1|123|jojo
1|NULL|bibi
3|789|zaza
3|012|NULL
```

file3.csv:

```
2|1a2b|1994|US
3|3c4e|1995|MG
4|5f6g|1996|FR
```

My desired output is like this, conserve the duplicate key and fill it with the data of anothers files, and the void columns is filling by NULL:

```
1|abc|123|jojo|NULL|NULL|NULL
1|def|123|jojo|NULL|NULL|NULL
1|abc|NULL|bibi|NULL|NULL|NULL
1|def|NULL|bibi|NULL|NULL|NULL
2|ghi|NULL|NULL|1a2b|1994|US
2|jkl|NULL|NULL|1a2b|1994|US
3|mno|789|zaza|3c4e|1995|MG
3|pqr|789|zaza|3c4e|1995|MG
3|mno|012|NULL|3c4e|1995|MG
3|pqr|012|NULL|3c4e|1995|MG
4|NULL|NULL|NULL|5f6g|1996|FR
```

How to do that with one awk scripts or by 2 steps ?

Comment: Seems like it would be simpler to just upload them to a mysql docker container run SQL queries, and transform the result.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `awk` for this, I'd use a pair of [`join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html) calls:

```
$ join -t'|' -j1 -a1 -a2 -e NULL -o 0,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2,2.3,2.4 \
       <(join -t'|' -j1 -a1 -a2 -e NULL -o 0,1.2,2.2,2.3 file1.csv file2.csv) \
       file3.csv
1|abc|123|jojo|NULL|NULL|NULL
1|abc|NULL|bibi|NULL|NULL|NULL
1|def|123|jojo|NULL|NULL|NULL
1|def|NULL|bibi|NULL|NULL|NULL
2|ghi|NULL|NULL|1a2b|1994|US
2|jkl|NULL|NULL|1a2b|1994|US
3|mno|789|zaza|3c4e|1995|MG
3|mno|012|NULL|3c4e|1995|MG
3|pqr|789|zaza|3c4e|1995|MG
3|pqr|012|NULL|3c4e|1995|MG
4|NULL|NULL|NULL|5f6g|1996|FR
```

(This requires that the files all be sorted on the first column like they are in your sample, and a shell like `bash`, `zsh`, or `ksh93` that supports `<(command)` redirection.)

The arguments and their meanings: `-t'|'` uses pipe as the column delimiter, `-j1` uses the first column as the join field, `-a1 -a2` does a full outer join of the two files, `-e NULL` uses the value `NULL` for empty columns, and the `-o column-spec` controls what columns are included in the output. (Needed with the `-a` options to get full results).

Comment: this exemple is just simple files, but in reality it is within more and bigger files, so why join cannot do it, the best way is with awk, i'd like too that the algo is more flexible for adding more columns and files